# How to display specific title on Customizer?

Tags: theme-customizer

Please find the below image. It will be more clear to understand my question.

[image]

I want to display the title that has been shown on above image in the Customizer.

How can I do that?

Comment: Hey hey, what have you tried so far and where exactly are you stuck? Please update your question for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [Custom Control for WP Customizer](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/customizer-objects/#custom-controls-sections-and-panels) and use it.
**For example:**

```
    class Sub_Section_Heading_Custom_Control extends WP_Customize_Control {

        //The type of control being rendered
        public $type = 'sub_section_heading';



        //Render the control in the customizer

        public function render_content() {

        ?>
            <div class="sub-section-heading-control">
                <?php if( !empty( $this->label ) ) { ?>
                    <h4 class="customize-control-title">
                          <?php echo esc_html( $this->label ); ?>
                    </h4>
                <?php } ?>

            </div>
        <?php
        }
    }
```

Add some CSS

```
.sub-section-heading-control 
    .customize-control-title{ 

   text-align: center;
   color: white;
   background-color: saddlebrown;
   padding: 10px;

    }
```

And add it to a section in Customizer:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('heading_post_content', array()); // dummy

$wp_customize->add_control( new Sub_Section_Heading_Custom_Control( 
            $wp_customize, 'heading_post_content',
            array(
                'label'   => __( 'Post Content', 'your-text-domain' ), // Set heading text here
                'section' => 'post_single', // set section id here
            )
        ) );
```

It should look like this:
[image: Custom Heading in Customizer Section]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks alot. It helped me to provide my own concept.

Comment: @EGWorldNP Glad to know that it helped you. Please mark this as your **Accepted Answer** to help other people searching for similar topic. Thanks.